# Telling when file was last accessed in C

Tags: c, windows

In Windows, if you go to a file's properties it shows the last access time right under the time last modified. This changes when I copy it.

How do I view this in C?

Comment: You asked [a question earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810035/determining-if-file-has-been-copied-or-not-in-c) which, according to later comments, was really this question. You should really have edited the old question (or deleted it) rather than ask a new one. At least you are now getting sensible answers...

Comment: @Floris IMHO the earlier question seemed to have a sensible answer even if it was was from an evil twin brother.  (or is that that good twin, Hmmm?) ;-)

Comment: @Floris Not really a fan of suggesting that new users delete questions; if they get into the habit of deleting every time there's a problem with their question, it'll just make things worse for them. Editing the original is definitely the right call.

Comment: @DennisMeng I agree - but I only noticed this question as duplicate after I had already replied to the old one, and after a sensible answer had been given to the rephrased (this) one.

Comment: @chux thanks for noticing. Definitely evil twins. I figured out what the "real" original question was and answered it; then noticed this "duplicate" was getting attention...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portable way of getting the last modified timestamp is by using [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) or [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).  If you want to go the Windows-only route (by directly calling a Windows API), see @xxbbcc's answer.

See [How can I get a file's size in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840148/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c) for a short piece of sample code that uses stat/fstat - only change for your purpose is that you'll want to read the `time_t st_mtime` field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GetFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get it. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has more details about file times.